# exception thrown in rcl_logging_rosout_remove_sublogger on destruction with a child logger with static lifetime

Tags: ros2, rclcpp

I believe this is likely a bug. Here is a minimal example and the output with a stack trace (made with backwardcpp):

```cpp
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>

rclcpp::Logger& getLogger() {
  static auto logger = rclcpp::get_logger("moveit");
  return logger;
}

// make the child logger the first time we use it
rclcpp::Logger getStaticChildLogger()
{
  static auto logger = [] {
    auto logger = getLogger().get_child("child");
    RCLCPP_INFO(logger, "making the child logger");
    return logger;
  }();
  return logger;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("dut_node");

  getLogger() = node->get_logger();
  RCLCPP_INFO(getLogger(), "node logger");

  RCLCPP_INFO(getStaticChildLogger(), "child node logger");
}
```

```
[INFO] [1698780244.672370104] [dut_node]: node logger
[INFO] [1698780244.672399117] [dut_node.child]: making the child logger
[INFO] [1698780244.672402452] [dut_node.child]: child node logger
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::exceptions::RCLError'
  what():  failed to call rcl_logging_rosout_remove_sublogger: Sub-logger 'dut_node.child' not exist., at ./src/rcl/logging_rosout.c:530
Stack trace (most recent call last):
#19   Object "", at 0xffffffffffffffff, in 
#18   Object "/home/tyler/code/ws_moveit/install/moveit_core/lib/moveit_core/logger_from_child_dut", at 0x55756bef8624, in _start
#17   Source "../csu/libc-start.c", line 392, in __libc_start_main_impl [0x7fad3c229e3f]
#16   Source "../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h", line 74, in __libc_start_call_main [0x7fad3c229d96]
#15   Source "./stdlib/exit.c", line 143, in exit [0x7fad3c24560f]
#14   Source "./stdlib/exit.c", line 113, in __run_exit_handlers [0x7fad3c245494]
#13   Source "/opt/ros/rolling/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/logger.hpp", line 92, in ~Logger [0x55756bef9467]
         89: rcpputils::fs::path
         90: get_logging_directory();
         91: 
      >  92: class Logger
         93: {
         94: public:
         95:   /// An enum for the type of logger level.
#12   Source "/usr/include/c++/11/bits/shared_ptr.h", line 122, in ~shared_ptr [0x55756bef93bd]
        119:    * pointer see `std::shared_ptr::owner_before` and `std::owner_less`.
        120:   */
        121:   template<typename _Tp>
      > 122:     class shared_ptr : public __shared_ptr<_Tp>
        123:     {
        124:       template<typename... _Args>
        125:    using _Constructible = typename enable_if<
#11   Source "/usr/include/c++/11/bits/shared_ptr_base.h", line 1154, in ~__shared_ptr [0x55756bef939d]
       1152:       __shared_ptr(const __shared_ptr&) noexcept = default;
       1153:       __shared_ptr& operator=(const __shared_ptr&) noexcept = default;
      >1154:       ~__shared_ptr() = default;
       1155: 
       1156:       template<typename _Yp, typename = _Compatible<_Yp>>
       1157:    __shared_ptr(const __shared_ptr<_Yp, _Lp>& __r) noexcept
#10   Source "/usr/include/c++/11/bits/shared_ptr_base.h", line 705, in ~__shared_count [0x55756bef9ee6]
        702:       ~__shared_count() noexcept
        703:       {
        704:    if (_M_pi != nullptr)
      > 705:      _M_pi->_M_release();
        706:       }
        707: 
        708:       __shared_count(const __shared_count& __r) noexcept
#9    Source "/usr/include/c++/11/bits/shared_ptr_base.h", line 168, in _M_release [0x55756befa64c]
        165:    if (__gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add_dispatch(&_M_use_count, -1) == 1)
        166:      {
        167:             _GLIBCXX_SYNCHRONIZATION_HAPPENS_AFTER(&_M_use_count);
      > 168:        _M_dispose();
        169:        // There must be a memory barrier between dispose() and destroy()
        170:        // to ensure that the effects of dispose() are observed in the
        171:        // thread that runs destroy().
#8    Object "/opt/ros/rolling/lib/librclcpp.so", at 0x7fad3cb27e06, in 
#7    Object "/opt/ros/rolling/lib/librclcpp.so", at 0x7fad3cafe6d8, in rclcpp::exceptions::throw_from_rcl_error(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcutils_error_state_s const*, void (*)())
#6    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7fad3c6ae1fd, in std::rethrow_exception(std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr)
#5    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7fad3c6ae276, in std::terminate()
#4    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7fad3c6ae20b, in 
#3    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7fad3c6a2b9d, in 
#2    Source "./stdlib/abort.c", line 79, in abort [0x7fad3c2287f2]
#1    Source "../sysdeps/posix/raise.c", line 26, in raise [0x7fad3c242475]
#0  | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 89, in __pthread_kill_internal
    | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 78, in __pthread_kill_implementation
      Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 44, in __pthread_kill [0x7fad3c2969fc]
Aborted (Signal sent by tkill() 1572362 1000)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote some documentation [here](https://github.com/jrutgeer/ROS2_assorted_docs/blob/main/ROS2_core/ROS2_logging.md#rosout): there is a hash table (`__logger_map`) that links logger and child logger names to the respective publisher.

I think this is the reason:

- The node goes out of scope,
- This  [calls](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/fff009a75100f2afd8ef1c3863620bf5ebe67708/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/node_interfaces/node_base.cpp#L130) `rcl_logging_rosout_fini_publisher_for_node`,
- which [calls](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/1b79535fa07fcc77c873adf5261308dac7a821ce/rcl/src/rcl/logging_rosout.c#L330-L330) `_rcl_logging_rosout_remove_logger_map`,
- This [iterates through](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/1b79535fa07fcc77c873adf5261308dac7a821ce/rcl/src/rcl/logging_rosout.c#L139-L143) `__logger_map` and 'unsets' all entries associates with that node,
- Then the child logger destructs and it fails to find its entry in the  `__logger_map` [here](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/1b79535fa07fcc77c873adf5261308dac7a821ce/rcl/src/rcl/logging_rosout.c#L529).

Quick fix that confirms above:

Change

```cpp
rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("dut_node");`
```

into

```cpp
static rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("dut_node");`
```

And there no longer is an exception, since the node outlives the loggers.

An unrelated remark:

Note that calling `get_child` on a *named* logger (i.e. a non-node logger such as `rclcpp::get_logger("moveit")`) throws an exception (as a named logger does not have a publisher).

So in your example code it is mandatory to issue `getLogger() = node->get_logger();`, before calling `getStaticChildLogger()`.

Comment: wow, thank you for figuring this out. is this what everyone who wants to use child loggers is doing?

Comment: side note, i discovered what you wrote about the exception and was trying to work around that here: https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/6e1f7f4cd87cb26bc8fee1892fe8346349e7bf5c/moveit_core/utils/src/logger.cpp#L64

Comment: thank you for your documentation, that was excellent, saved me from trying to go read all that rcl code to answer this question.

Comment: I think most people use node loggers and child loggers within a node, so it's impossible that the logger outlives the node.

Comment: ChrisL said in a meeting that it might be possible to get rosout logging without being associated with a node, and we should reach out to him for more info. I created this issue to try to summarize for him what I've tried so far and ask for his input: https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/2350

Comment: Glad at least _someone_ read that documentation! ;-) The code is ultimately undocumented unfortunately.

Comment: I'd be happy to try to help you upstream that documentation to docs.ros.org if you'd like to make a PR. It would be good to have to be more discoverable. I can't merge changes there but I could review it.